# Incompatibility between `floatrow` and `cleveref`

Tags: cleveref, floatrow

Consider the following MWE. If you comment out the line `\usepackage{cleveref}`, it works fine. However, if this line is not commented, the `pdflatex` command just stalls (no error is shown). Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\newfloatcommand{falgbox}{algorithm}[\nocapbeside]
\begin{algorithm}[h]
    \falgbox[0.7\columnwidth]{%
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Function{Register}{\,}

            \EndFunction
        \end{algorithmic}}{
        \caption{The Register(\,) function.\label{alg:Register}}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I would say this is a consequence of the way `floatrow` defines counters etc.

Comment: Send the author of `cleveref` a message. Maybe he make the programs compatible, if possible.